# Reducing execution time of MySQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I want to optimize the execution time (50 sec) of the following update command.

```
    UPDATE matches a
    JOIN players AS b 
    ON a.player1_name = b.player_name
    SET a.player1_id = b.id
    WHERE a.player1_id = 0
```

The table *matches* has approximately 10000 entries and table *players* 4000 entries.

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: That was it. I thought I had already done it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have indexes on a.player1_name, b.player_name and a.player1_id.